# split a linked list into 2 even lists containing the smallest and largest numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Given a linked list of integers in random order, split it into two new linked lists such that the difference in the sum of elements of each list is maximal and the length of the lists differs by no more than 1 (in the case that the original list has an odd number of elements).  *I can't assume that the numbers in the list are unique.*

The algorithm I thought of was to do a merge sort on the original linked list (*O(n·log n)* time, *O(n)* space ) and then use a recursive function to walk to the end of the list to determine its length, doing the splitting while the recursive function is unwinding.  The recursive function is *O(n)* time and *O(n)* space.

Is this the optimal solution?  I can post my code if someone thinks it's relevant.

Comment: If your linked list implementation keeps a size property, then you only have to walk half way down the list to chop it in half. (Might want to check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com !)

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler:  No size property, just a very plain jane basic linked list, really nothing more than a bunch of nodes linked together.

Comment: Unless your exam requires you to implement the sort you can also use Collections.sort to do the sorting.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were implementing the linked list yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not optimal; you can find the [median of a list in *O(n)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), then put half of them in one list (smaller than median or equal, upto list size be n/2) and half of them in another list ((n+1)/2).  Their sum difference is maximized, and there is no need to sort (*O(n·log(n)*).  All things will be done in *O(n)* (space and time).

Comment: The link you provided seems to indicate that this algorithm is suited to random access arrays.  Are you sure this works for linked lists?

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: If necessary, we could copy the list first to an array and later back, still O(n).

Comment: One more thing, based on this analysis http://www.soe.ucsc.edu/classes/cmps102/Spring05/selectAnalysis.pdf of the Median of Medians algorithm, it requires that the elements in the array be unique. I can't assume that.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann:  Yeah, I thought of that right after I made the comment.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes, I just see your second comment, no there is no need to elements of array be unique, the link you saying is more specific (it shows at most 50*n call it doesn't work with order), This is a known O(n) algorithm for finding kth element in list (not set see wiki) so if you find in O(n) in list it's easier to find it in O(n) in set. the analysis is simple (see wiki).

Comment: +1 because you seem to be right. But do you maybe have better reference for the median of medians algorithm?  The wikipedia article isn't that good.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes, CLRS book is good for this(described it well), see table of contents http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11866&mode=toc

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need recursive function? While sorting list, you can count it elements. Then just split it in half. This drops O(n) space requirement.

Even if you can't count list length while sorting, it still can be split in O(n) time and O(1) space: get two list iterators on the beginning, advance first 2 elements at each step, second 1 element each step. When first reaches list end - cut at second.

Comment: I'm already splitting in O(n) time.  It takes O(n) space because I'm making copies of the original LL.